# I want to filter in the list if the text box value is changed using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to filter in the list if the text box value is changed if the 
JSON Returned in Ajax call is as I am using two different model.
Filteration should show hide or just filter the data I am providing you the JSON data what I am getting from the ajax call. Thanks

```
    Data = [{"code":"Grand Financial","cls":"Branch","Chk":true},{"code":"Joan Group","cls":"Branch","Chk":true}]



     var searchModel, advisorGroupModel;
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/ASPNET/Reports/GetAdvisorGroups',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    advisorGroupModel = {
                        advisorGroup: ko.observableArray(data)
                    };
                    ko.applyBindings(advisorGroupModel, document.getElementById("advisorGroupModel"));
                }
            })

            var searchModel = {
                searchQuery: ko.observable('')
            };
            searchModel.searchHandle= ko.dependentObservable(function () {
                var code = this.searchQuery().toLowerCase();
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(advisorGroupModel, function (beer) {
                    debugger;
                    return beer.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(code) >= 0;
                });
                console.log(search);
            }, searchModel)

            ko.applyBindings(searchModel, document.getElementById("searchModel"));
        });

<div id="searchModel">
    <input data-bind="value: searchQuery, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
    <h6 data-bind="text: searchQuery"></h6>
</div>
<div class="CheckBoxListGroup" id="advisorGroupModel">
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'advisorGroupTemplate', foreach: advisorGroup, as: 'singleAdvisorGroup' }"></ul>
    <script type="text/html" id="advisorGroupTemplate">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: code, id: code, checked: Chk }" name="GroupsSel">
            <label data-bind="attr: { for: code }, text: '' + code + ' (' + cls + ')' "></label>

        </li>
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't bind your display to the entire list, bind your display to a computed function that returns the filtered list or returns all items when there are no filters.

then on your keyup call your filterlist function that filters the list removing the ones that do not match your filter

Comment: Can you make a JSFIDDLE for it, I am new to it, Don't really know much about it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JTimperley/pyCTN/13/

found an existing one, taken from http://geekswithblogs.net/jtimperley/archive/2013/07/29/knockout.js---filtering-sorting-and-paging.aspx